# ARGOCD- Cache error (Unable to load data: error getting cached app state: cache: key is missing)

Tags: kubernetes, devops, argocd

I tried to update our tst environment ArgoCD from v2.3.0 to 2.4.0. update was successful. I was able to login and see all the applications. But when I open the application and click on a resource(pod, deployment, etc) it is giving me the following error instead of showing the details

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's enough to restart only applicationController's statefulset, ie.

```
kubectl rollout restart statefulset -n argocd argocd-application-controller
```

Probably first occured since v2.4.13+19ec34e argocd revision.
We have installed v2.4.12+41f54aa on other environment and it's working fine.

Original discussion here: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/10666

Answer (score 0):

In a dev/test/learning context, I resolved this issue by deleting Argocd networkpolicies:

```
adminuser@master:~/argocd-app-config$ kubectl get networkpolicies -n argocd
NAME                                              POD-SELECTOR                                              AGE
argocd-application-controller-network-policy      app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-application-controller      4h48m
argocd-applicationset-controller-network-policy   app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-applicationset-controller   4h48m
argocd-dex-server-network-policy                  
[...]
 
adminuser@master:~/argocd-app-config$ kubectl delete networkpolicies -n argocd argocd-application-controller-network-policy argocd-applicationset-controller-network-policy [...]

networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io "argocd-application-controller-network-policy" deleted
networkpolicy.networking.k8s.io "argocd-applicationset-controller-network-policy" deleted
[...]
```